# Mongoose update sub document if exists

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have following model :

```
var VoteSchema = new Schema({
    up : Boolean
    , createdBy:{type:ObjectId, ref:'users'}
    , createdOn : {type:Date, default:Date.now}
});

var QuestionSchema = newSchema({
    title:String
    , description:String
    , votes : [VoteSchema]
    , createdBy:{type:ObjectId, ref:'users'}
    , createdOn : {type:Date, default:Date.now}
});

var Question = mongoose.model('questions',QuestionSchema);
```

Suppose `user1` is logged in user and `question1` is current / viewing question.The user can `upvote`({up:true}) or `downvote`({up:false}) a question at any time. **How can I `add` a new `vote` if a `user1` have not casted a vote for `question1` else `update` the vote.**

I have been able to write the following lines of code:

```
QuestionSchema.statics.castVote = function(questionId, vote) {
    //NOTE : vote.createdBy equalsto loggedInUserID

    Q.nbind(Question.findOne, Question)({
        $and:[
            {_id:questionId},
            {'votes.createdBy':vote.createdBy}
        ]
    }).then(function(doc) {

        if(doc) {
           //I am clue less
           //doc.votes is a list of votes for this question
           // how can I get the particular vote casted by the user - vote.createdBy
        }else {
           //Question.votes.push(vote);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: I suppose you are trying to do 'upsert'.check this out.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Comment: @suish This isn't an `upsert` it's pushing an item onto the array if it does not exist or updating in place where it does. The array is embedded.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So you're part of the way there, but of course when you don't find a `doc` then you will not have a `doc` to work with in the callback. MongoDB has native ways of handling these sorts of updates, but of course you do need to test for the **match** as you are.

What we can do here is just work within the `true` or `false` condition of where the document exists.

Considering `vote.value` to be your `true` or `false` for the "upvote"

Where you do find that there is a matching document you can issue an update like this:

```
Question.update(
  { 
    _id: questionId, 
    "votes.createdBy" vote.createdBy,
    "votes.up": {"$ne": vote.value }
  },
  { $set: { "votes.$.up": vote.value } }
);
```

So that matches and uses a [positional](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) `$` operator to make sure the correct *index* of the matching item is updated. What I added there makes sure that you don't even touch the document where the `vote.vaule` is already of the same value.

And in the false condition you want to [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) onto the array with the **new** item:

```
Question.update(
  { 
    _id: questionId
  },
  { 
    $push: { 
      "votes": {
        "up": vote.value,
        "createdBy": vote.createdBy
      }
    }
  }
);
```

Of course add the callback details where `writeConcern` is applied, which you probably do.

Comment: superb, perhaps the only way to tackle this kind of  problem,seriously. Is it possible to get the value of `positional - $` after `$setting`. I got this information in cb `[ 1,
  { updatedExisting: true, n: 1, connectionId: 93, err: null, ok: 1 } ]`.

Comment: @Lekhnath Um, not really sure. You're looking at the *numAffected* part there. The third argument in the callback is supposed to be the *rawResponse* (whatever that is) so you could look into that and see if there is anything interesting.

Comment: `update()` now deprecated. `updateOne()` for a single document update recommended