# How do I correctly Update a mongoose/mongodb sub subdocument

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a group which have tasks, which have Items. I want to update the details of a particular Item for a particular Task for a Particular group.I have the group ID, the Task ID and the Item ID and I tried to follow and adapt the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22039985/mongoose-update-sub-document-if-exists) but I get no errors and just get `0` as the number affected. Or am I approaching this wrong?

```
var deferred = Q.defer();
  var set = {};
  for (var field in item) {
    set['ITEMS.$.'+field] = item[field];
  }
  Group.update(
    {_id:ID, "TASKS._id":taskId, "TASKS.$.ITEMS._id": task.ID},
    {$set : set},
    function(error, numAffected){
      if (error) { deferred.reject(new Error(error)); }
        deferred.resolve(numAffected);
    });
```

Comment: These questions keep occurring. This is not how the `$` operator works (refer to http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/), and it's not clear what you want to accomplish. You can't have `a.$` and `b.$` in a single query. These problems appear because your data model relies way too much on embedding rather than association. As a rule of thumb, if you have an embedded list in an embedded list (or associations between embedded lists), you're doing it wrong. Unclutter your data structure. As a guess, try making tasks first class citizens.

Comment: @mnemosyn firstly it is a requirement on a project to keep this in a single collection, 2nd may not be the recommended way in many cases to keep in a single collection, but there are cases where it has its use cases. Finally, and not trying to be smart, but I don't believe I could be any clearer with what I am trying to achieve `"I have a group which have tasks, which have Items. I want to update the details of a particular Item"` if you can tell what am I not being clear about I am happy to add more detail, Thanks

Comment: I agree. While over normalization is a bad thing, some approaches can be used. A task, for example, needs to be documented. Only one of the fields denotes the group this task is associated with. And even that might change. So moving a task from Team A to Team B changes a lot more in the database than simply changing the reference to the assigned team. Plus, a team may have hundreds of tasks, each associated with additional documentation, information and whatnot. You'll reach the 16MB document limit for a group pretty fast. Another indicator that tasks should be a first class citizen.

Comment: @jonnieM: Ahem, there is no schema in MongoDB. You can put all kinds of different documents in _one_ collection, not sharing a single field except for `_id`. But: I'd really like to know the use cases where it makes sense to have all stored in a single collection just by decision.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I understand that, but the collection will actually be quite small, usually no more then 10 tasks to a group with max10-15 items, so I don't think the limit is an issue.

Comment: @jonnieM: Since you can have a lot of different documents in one collection, you can use best practices _and_ obey your constraint.

Comment: @jonnieM: what's not clear to me is the update semantics: where `TASKS._id = a AND TASKS.$.ITEMS._id = b, set ITEMS.$.foo` - how would I map the document I found using the constraints to the `ITEMS.$`? The match would be `TASKS.$` and I can change `TASKS.$.ITEMS.foo` and so forth, but I can't go from one list to another using the match index `$`. "A particular item" makes sense to me as a human, but I don't see how the criteria identify an item (unless it's a mistake in the question and you really want to modify `'TASKS.$.ITEMS.' + field`).

Comment: @mnemosyn I understand what you mean. I clearly didn't understand how the `$` works, thanks for clearing it up